# Share an Apple individual Dev. Account with team members

Tags: ios

I am trying to share my individual Apple developer account with other team members of my developer team. We develop as hobbyists, so there is no chance of getting a company dev account.

The only way to do this seems to be to share the private key of the individual account across the other developers MacBooks. As it is not intended by Apple to do so, this is not really an option for us.

Is there any other way to enable all team members to debug their code on their iPads, without sharing the private key?

The App-Store things don't have to be accessible by the other team members. My question is only related to debugging on the other devices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no way to add additional developers to an individual developer account. If getting a company account is out of the question, the only other solution is for every team member to get (and pay for) their own individual developer account.